# Rails 4 JSON attribute type not working with Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I forked a repo from someone I'm collaborating with, and I'm just trying to get my development environment up and running. One of the migrations has a `json` attribute and we're using Postgres for both dev and production:

```rb
class CreateExams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :exams do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.json :exam
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

#### database.yml

```yaml
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: examgen_development
  host: localhost
```

When I run the `rake db:migrate`, I get an error that would lead me to believe that PG doesn't support JSON column types:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  type "json" does not exist
```

But I know Postgres 9.2 supports JSON (i.e. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/datatype-json.html).

Interestingly, when I check the version of PG I'm using with 'psql' it shows 9.0.4. Whereas when I use 'postgres' it shows 9.2.1. So I'm not exactly sure what version I'm using and how to go about switching back and forth.

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.0.4

postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.1
```

Does anyone have thoughts as to why I'm getting that Postgres error?

Comment: How did you install postgres, through brew?

Comment: Yup - I installed it a while ago w/ homebrew

Comment: Try to update it, brew doctor -> brew update -> brew upgrade postgresql, then try to see if your version are updated.

Comment: upon running 'brew upgrade postgresql' I get 'Error: postgresql-9.2.1 already installed'

Comment: You ran "brew update" then "brew upgrade postgresql"? I am on version postgresql-9.2.4

Comment: Also do you have the last pg gem? http://rubygems.org/gems/pg 0.16.0?

Comment: OK, battled with homebrew a little, but now I'm definitely using postgres 9.2.4. Also explicitly installed v0.16.0 of the pg gem in my gemfile. Still getting that same error.

Comment: Did you rake db:reset then rake db:migrate?

Comment: Yeah, still no luck unfortunately (btw - really appreciate your help)

Comment: No problem, sorry another question, which version of Rails are you on? Ah shit, just saw the title, Rail 4...

Comment: Are you certain you are using rails 4, what do you get back when you type "rails -v" in your directory?

Comment: Yup, certain I'm running rails 4. I still don't understand the distinction between 'psql --version' and 'postgres --version'. When I run them both, they both display different versions. I.e.'psql --version = psql (PostgreSQL) 9.0.4' and 'postgres --version PostgreSQL 9.2.4'

postgres --version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so it turns out at one point I had installed postgres via homebrew, and had also done so with Postgres.app at a different time. I began to realize this by checking the version of 'psql' and 'postgres' and noticed the distinction.

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.0.4

postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4
```

I uninstalled Postgres.app using their documentation [here](http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_22) and then using homebrew ensured I was using the most recent version of postgres.